# Convert JSON from GET request into text boxes in C# Winforms Application

Tags: c#, json, winforms, api

I am quite new to C# and I am looking for some help into the following.

I have written some code (below) that utilises the companies house API to get information relating to companies. The information is returned in JSON format.

What I need to do it take certain information and put it into text boxes I already have on the form. The code I have written works as I can get it to return in the message box but I can't work out how to populate it into text boxes.

```
private void getFromCompaniesHouse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Compile request url
            string url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + txtCompanyNumber.Text;

            // Encode API key to ASCII
            string api_key = "yfhOb66cRn7ZL1VgdFjVur5cs8u6j__bcNnKj9Qs:";
            string encodedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(api_key));

            // Make get request using url and encoded API key
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedKey);
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Make Request", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

The JSON returned looks like this:

```
{  
"accounts":{  
"accounting_reference_date":{  
"month":"12",
"day":"31"
},
"last_accounts":{  
"type":"group",
"made_up_to":"2015-12-31"
},
"next_made_up_to":"2016-12-31",
"next_due":"2017-09-30",
"overdue":false
},
"company_number":"08867781",
"annual_return":{  
"last_made_up_to":"2016-06-20",
"overdue":false
},
"jurisdiction":"england-wales",
"has_been_liquidated":false,
"date_of_creation":"2014-01-29",
"undeliverable_registered_office_address":false,
"company_name":"VIRGIN ATLANTIC LIMITED",
"registered_office_address":{  
"address_line_2":"Fleming Way",
"locality":"Crawley",
"country":"United Kingdom",
"region":"West Sussex",
"address_line_1":"Company Secretariat - The VHQ",
"postal_code":"RH10 9DF"
},
"type":"ltd",
"last_full_members_list_date":"2016-06-20",
"sic_codes":[  
"70100"
],
"has_insolvency_history":false,
"etag":"cbab10bb8b9dc1db442cb585a63ae208c1265100",
"company_status":"active",
"has_charges":false,
"previous_company_names":[  
{  
"name":"VIRGIN ATLANTIC (HOLDINGS) LIMITED",
"effective_from":"2014-01-29",
"ceased_on":"2014-05-30"
}
],
"confirmation_statement":{  
"next_made_up_to":"2017-06-20",
"overdue":false,
"next_due":"2017-07-04"
},
"links":{  
"self":"/company/08867781",
"filing_history":"/company/08867781/filing-history",
"officers":"/company/08867781/officers"
},
"registered_office_is_in_dispute":false,
"can_file":true
}
```

** UPDATE **

I have updated my code to the following:

```
private void getFromCompaniesHouse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Compile request url
            string url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + txtCompanyNumber.Text;

            // Encode API key to ASCII
            string api_key = "yfhOb66cRn7ZL1VgdFjVur5cs8u6j__bcNnKj9Qs:";
            string encodedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(api_key));

            // Make get request using url and encoded API key
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedKey);
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);  //Turns your raw string into a key value lookup
            string company_name = json["company_name"].ToObject<string>();

            txtBusinessName.Text = company_name;

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Make Request", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I can pull things from the `RootObject` class but cannot gain access to anything else for example in the `RegisteredOfficeAddress` class. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to help without knowing what the json looks like, where the "certain information" is and/or  if you know how to deserialize it

Comment: Do you have a defined structure for the JSON coming back?

Comment: there's a few steps here. Generally you want to use a library to transform the JSON to a C# class (google C# deserialize json etc), then you can pull info out of there and stick it on text boxes just like you'd normally set the text.

Comment: I've edited the post to show what the JSON looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample console app (using JSON.NET) that accesses your company info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = GetFromCompaniesHouse();

            task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task GetFromCompaniesHouse()
        {
            var url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/08867781";
            var apiKey = "yfhOb66cRn7ZL1VgdFjVur5cs8u6j__bcNnKj9Qs:";
            var encodedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiKey));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {encodedKey}");

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(content);

                Console.WriteLine($"Company: {company.company_name}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class LastAccounts
    {
        public string made_up_to { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountingReferenceDate
    {
        public string month { get; set; }
        public string day { get; set; }
    }

    public class Accounts
    {
        public LastAccounts last_accounts { get; set; }
        public string next_due { get; set; }
        public bool overdue { get; set; }
        public string next_made_up_to { get; set; }
        public AccountingReferenceDate accounting_reference_date { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisteredOfficeAddress
    {
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string locality { get; set; }
        public string address_line_2 { get; set; }
        public string postal_code { get; set; }
        public string address_line_1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PreviousCompanyName
    {
        public string effective_from { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string ceased_on { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfirmationStatement
    {
        public string last_made_up_to { get; set; }
        public string next_made_up_to { get; set; }
        public string next_due { get; set; }
        public bool overdue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string filing_history { get; set; }
        public string officers { get; set; }
        public string charges { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public Accounts accounts { get; set; }
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        public bool has_been_liquidated { get; set; }
        public RegisteredOfficeAddress registered_office_address { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string last_full_members_list_date { get; set; }
        public string date_of_creation { get; set; }
        public List<string> sic_codes { get; set; }
        public bool undeliverable_registered_office_address { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string company_number { get; set; }
        public string jurisdiction { get; set; }
        public bool has_insolvency_history { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public string company_status { get; set; }
        public bool has_charges { get; set; }
        public List<PreviousCompanyName> previous_company_names { get; set; }
        public ConfirmationStatement confirmation_statement { get; set; }
        public Links links { get; set; }
        public bool registered_office_is_in_dispute { get; set; }
        public bool can_file { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how to implement this in my code.

Say I wanted to pull the company_name and put it into a textbox called txtBusiness_Name.Text?

Comment: Not counting data binding:

    txtBusiness_Name.Text = company.company_name;

Comment: I have updated my code as above but cannot gain access to any thing other than the RootObject?

Comment: Updated response above to include fully functional sample app.